# Codeigniter file upload doesn't get to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I need to upload a file in my server on file input change. I used the library for file input from [Codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

index

```
<form class="image" method="POST">
    <input id="image-value" data-id="{{id}}" name="{{picture}}" class="image-box-{{id}}" data-type="{{type}}" type="file" value="{{picture}}" />
</form>
```

here is the view where I made a form that accepts an image

script

```
$('[id="image-value"]').change(function(e) {
 var file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];   
 var form_data = new FormData();

 form_data.append('file', file_data);

 $.ajax({ // 02102016 AA: picture_caption
    url: './upload_picture/',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,                         
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

when triggered, the script gets the file from the index and send it to
my controller

controller

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $config['upload_path'] = './data/picture/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
}

function upload_picture() {
// $data = Array();
log_message("debug", "do_upload: ".$this->upload->do_upload());
if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
    log_message("debug", "data: ".$this->upload->data());
}
```

the problem (i think) is in how i passed the data from my controller
as the value of `do_upload` is still **false** even the the data has been
passed from the script

### I found a great solution!

> turns out it just needed `"file"` as do_upload() parameter. thanks
>   for this great [article](http://codenimbus.com/2012/02/12/codeigniter-plupload-problems-a-solution/)! saved my life!

Comment: missing enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form

Comment: @VinodVT, i added `<form class="image" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` but i still get false

Comment: didn't you missing action of form

Comment: i think it doesnt need an action because it can be triggered with my script @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0

Answer (score 0):

Function name included but controller name not included ..

```
$('[id="image-value"]').change(function(e) {
var file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();

form_data.append('file', file_data);

$.ajax({ // 02102016 AA: picture_caption
url: 'controllerName/upload_picture/', //add the controller.
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
data: form_data,                         
type: 'post',
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.error("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

});

controller

```
    $var = $_POST['file'];
    print_r($var);
     if($this->input->post('file')) {

    $config['upload_path'] = 'upload'; 
    $config['file_name'] = $var; // this may be needed
    $config['overwrite'] = 'TRUE';
    $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config["max_size"] = '1024';
    $config["max_width"] = '400';
    $config["max_height"] = '400';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {               
        $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        print_r( $this->data['error']);
    } else {
        print_r("success");                                      
    }
```

Comment: this isnt the case. my controller is called as the log is displayed.